# How to handle Segoe UI in pixel perfect layout (glyph "margin")

Tags: xaml, layout, windows-store-apps

i am fighting with the layout of my windows store app. My problem is with the segoe ui font that I am using for the labels of some textboxes.
I have a borderless label above a textbox with a border like this:

```
LABEL
_____________
|__TEXTBOX___|
```

My problem is, that the font of the label does not align perfectly with the left border of the textbox.
First I though that it must be the label padding or something, maybe a padding or margin in the control template. But this is not the case. The true reason is the space around the glyphs within the font itself. Depending on the first letter or the size of the font the gap is bigger or smaller.

Is there a way to perfectly align the label text and the textbox independant of the first letter or the font size? Or do I really have to place every label in a different position to reduce this problem?

Comment: Ditch label's unless you actually need them and use TextBlock's instead. They're heavier than TextBlock's are. As for the glyph padding of a font there's not much easy way around it, could just throw a small negative margin setter on the control template if that extra pixel or two is that troublesome.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, I know of the difference between Label and TextBlock and in that case I want the functionality of a Label. Yeah negative margins and stuff are not really the problem, my problem is that I have a lot of these elements. I want to have a common style for them, but that would not work in that case.